# UIButton with Animation Image doesn't showing

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiimage

I have found posts that concern with UIButton with Animation Image.
However i didn't found any solutions.

Here is my code.

```
UIImage *imageOne=[UIImage imageNamed:@"1Ads.png"];
UIImage *imageTwo=[UIImage imageNamed:@"2Ads.png"];
UIImage *imageThree=[UIImage imageNamed:@"3Ads.png"];

NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:imageOne,imageTwo,imageThree, nil];
self.btnAds.imageView.animationDuration = 7.0;
self.btnAds.imageView.animationImages = arr;
[self.btnAds.imageView startAnimating];
```

It's doesn't showing anything in View.

How can i do it?

Comment: try to set : animationRepeatCount.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the imageView property of UIButton. You can create an animation like this:

```
[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
myButton.imageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"],
                              nil];

myButton.imageView.animationDuration = 0.5;
[myButton.imageView startAnimating];
```